# Подгрузить содержимое файла tpl через ajax

Tags: ajax, tpl

Добрый день.
В общем хочу поинтересоваться как подгрузить содержимое файла `tpl` через `ajax`.
Насколько я понимаю это возможно делать только с `php` и `js` файлами.
Подгрузить нужно именно код, а не данные с БД.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Срендерить шаблон и с помощью `js` вставить его в `DOM`.

Comment: Можно ссылку на развернутую статью? или на наводки какиенибудь.
Я курил гугл и пока не чего не нашел